# htaccess block and allow sites from the same domain name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip, root

I run a service where I offer css files and scripts and images for a third party website www.myfantasyleague.com  that is a football hosting service for fantasy football and recently they have went through some changes over the last couple of years.

I am trying to block certain websites on their servers that are using my work fraudulently, while allowing the folks whom purchase my work on the same domain to be able to use my work and it not be blocked by the HTA file. Once you create a football site MFL gives it a permanent server number and 5-digit code that never changes now from each year it stays the same. Here is a link to a MFL search for the word football, and you can see there are many sites and if you click on a few they all have different 5 digit IDs and some have different server ID’s.

The site I want to start with to block, would be this site url below, and the MFL domain has an option to have http and https now, so getting both protocols would be idea.

SITE TO BLOCK EXAMPLE

https://www67.myfantasyleague.com/2019/home/63928#0

SITE TO ALLOW EXAMPLE

http://www51.myfantasyleague.com/2019/home/46087#0

On myfantasyleague domains they give each site its own 5-digit unique code at the end of the url, and also many are on different server id’s, like the www67 and the www51, and you see those 2 links one is https and one is http.

In the past I use to use this code below and it will still work today, however once I add it to my root access file, it takes out both sites and I can’t have that, as I want to be able to control which sites are blocked by the server number and the 5-digit league ID if possible.

CODE THAT I TRIED THAT WORKED BUT KILLS ALL SITES FROM THAT DOMAIN NAME.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} https?://(www\.)?www(67).myfantasyleague.com.+(63928) [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|js|css)$ [L]
```

Maybe i can turn that URL to be blocked into the actual IP and try blocking the IP?

I don't know what else to try and it might not even be possible i dont know. I appreciate any and all feedback.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Though the pattern you posted certainly can be improved there is no reason why it should "block" all referrers from that host, *if those sites send a referrer header at all* ... Keep in mind that such header is optional and can be modified easily, so anyone can work around limitations you implement based on that header. 
Blocking an IP on the other hand means you block *all* services from that host which is not what you want, as I understand. The numerical addition to the "www" prefix indicates that the service operator uses sharding to balance request load, an old and outdated approach. You can expect that to change any time, either for individual sites or in general, so better not rely on it. You are only interested in the numerical ID at the end of the referring URL.

Your issue with that approach you posted however is the actual rewriting rule: it is syntactically invalid. So I would expect it to raise an internal error, thus blocking *all* requests. I would suggest something like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/63928$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/63927$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/63926$
RewriteRule ^ [F,NC]
```

This would actively white list specific sites by mentioning their numerical ID and block all other requests by sending out a "Forbidden" header.

Please note that I have not actually tested above code, it might contain some minor glitch which you might have to fix. For such things it is important to have access to the http servers error log file. Not sure if you have it in your situation...

Comment: I tried this code to test, but unfortunately it was blocking the 5 digit code i was asking it to whitelist also, and this likely wouldnt be great for me if it was working as if i have over 1000 sites that i want to not block, i no way have all of their 5 digit ID to allow them access. It would be much easier for me to control the ones i dont want to allow access to, as it is a small handful of sites. Thank you

Comment: Then just turn the white list into a black list by removing the trailing exclamation mark from the conditions. Why things fail for you is another thing, I suspect you get an internal server error. Are you _really_ certain that the rewriting module is loaded, activated and granted for you _at all_ in that environment?

Comment: Not 100% sure about the header referral but it did work in the past years..........
 .....When you say remove the exclamation mark, see the code below as i did that and unless i am not fully having all the code in there, it is still blocking all sites from that domain when i try to deploy test it. RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /46087$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/63928$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/63926$ RewriteRule ^ [F,NC]

Comment: You appear to ignore my hints about issue with using rewriting at all. So you _are_ really certain that the rewriting module is available? Then you need to dig deeper. What does "block" actually mean for you? What exactly? What result do you get from your service when you try to access the URLs?

Comment: Block means to stop the website i add with the 5 digit code from hotlinking to my site, while allow all others to flow through......Nobody is ignoring you, if you can post code that works i will use it and see what it does.... if you cant then please dont worry about helping further as i am asking for help meaning i dont know enough to do it myself......When i try to access the URLs after i added the HTA each time, the sites load fine but each block all css, png, scripts from my domain and we only want one to be blocked and the other to go through as it isnt in the hta to block...

Comment: You miss understood my question... I did understand what you mean by blocking, sure. I asked about _how_ that block looks like for you. Because that might shed a light onto what is going wrong, why everything is blocked instead of just the sites you want to have blocked. There might occur a server internal error which will indeed lead to no request getting served. Or the server might send an explicit "forbidden" header. But those are different things, you will have to find out what is actually going on. We cannot do that for you, only you have access.

Comment: I repeatedly asked about whether the rewriting module is available to you at all, you did not answer to that. Do you know if it is? How?

Comment: I suggest you start debugging so that we can get closed to the cause of the issue. When the rules are in place and all requests fail, then open a browsers console (typically F12), chose the networking tab in there, make a full reload of the page and observe the single requests. Pick one targeting your service and check _why_ it fails. What do you see? What return code, is it in the 500 range or the 400 range? What error message is specified? Those are the things I asked about.